# Combining column values from a historical ledger into a daily summary in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A little new to SQL and had a question. I am working with a view that contains a historical ledger/record of price changes for all products. Here is an example of what this view looks like:

```
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+-----+
| SKU | PriceChangeDate | NewPrice | OldPrice |  RN |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+-----+
| ABC | 1/1/2017 1:00   | $7.00    | $6.50    |   1 |
| ABC | 1/1/2017 1:30   | $6.75    | $7.00    |   2 |
| ABC | 1/1/2017 1:45   | $7.25    | $6.75    |   3 |
| DEF | 1/1/2017 1:05   | $8.75    | $8.00    |   1 |
| DEF | 1/1/2017 1:25   | $10.00   | $8.75    |   2 |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+-----+
```

The RN column was created by me, after having created a row number column by partitioning over `SKU` and ordering by `PriceChangeDate`.

What I'm trying to do is create a query that will return each distinct `SKU`, its most recent `NewPrice`, and its oldest `OldPrice` for a single day, to essentially show the starting price and ending price for the day. It would look something like this:

```
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+-----+
| SKU | PriceChangeDate | NewPrice | OldPrice |  RN |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+-----+
| ABC | 1/1/2017 1:45   | $7.25    | $6.50    |   3 |
| DEF | 1/1/2017 1:25   | $10.00   | $8.00    |   2 |
+-----+-----------------+----------+----------+-----+
```

I know that I have to group by `SKU`, but I'm not sure how I could make this happen. Any tips/ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide table structures and data examples not in image format

Comment: Please don't link to images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question + https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: done. sorry, i'm new to stack overflow as well haha

Comment: The only vague thing is the "for a single day" part. If there was a line with SKU=ABC and PriceChangeDate= another day, should there be two records, one for each day? Or one only, with max and min of every day?

Comment: also: which sql server version?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis there should be two records, one for each day. Sql Server management studio v17.1 (2017)

Answer (score 0):

First, to not murder query performance, you will want to add a column to hold the date of the timestamps (in the proper time zone) and a table index `(SKU, PriceChangeActualDate)`.

Then the solution will involve writing a [window query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
     SKU INT NOT NULL--use an appropriate data type here
    ,[Timestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[Date] AS CONVERT(DATE, [Timestamp]) PERSISTED
    ,NewPrice MONEY NOT NULL
    ,OldPrice MONEY NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY(SKU, [Timestamp])
)
--create an index on (SKU, [Date]) to help speed up query performance on large record sets

INSERT INTO @MyTable
(
     SKU
    ,[Timestamp]
    ,NewPrice
    ,OldPrice
)
VALUES
     (1, '2017-01-01 01:00', 7.00, 6.50)
    ,(1, '2017-01-01 01:30', 6.75, 7.00)
    ,(1, '2017-01-01 01:45', 7.25, 6.75)
    ,(2, '2017-01-01 01:05', 8.75, 8.00)
    ,(2, '2017-01-01 01:25', 10.00, 8.75)

SELECT DISTINCT
     SKU
    ,[Date]
    ,[FirstUpdate] = MIN([Timestamp]) OVER(PARTITION BY SKU, [Date])
    ,[LastUpdate] = MAX([Timestamp]) OVER(PARTITION BY SKU, [Date])
    ,StartingPrice = FIRST_VALUE(OldPrice) OVER(PARTITION BY SKU, [Date] ORDER BY [Timestamp] ASC)
    ,EndingPrice = FIRST_VALUE(NewPrice) OVER(PARTITION BY SKU, [Date] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC)
FROM @MyTable
ORDER BY
     SKU
    ,[Date]
```

I have added a column `[Date]` as a `PERSISTED`, computed column so it can be indexed (I didn't index it in the above code; see the comment), assuming the timestamps are in the proper time zone (another thing to avoid like the plague: time values without a clear time zone).

Note that [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql) requires SQL Server 2012 or newer.

---

And a couple (personal) stylistic guidelines since you are new:

1. Put column aliases first, as this is [much easier to read](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) (everything is left-justified this way instead of randomly to the right somewhere, sometimes overflowing to a new line depending on your editor)
2. Be *very* conspicuous with time zones. You should also check out the [`DATETIMEOFFSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql) type
3. Avoid [Hungarian naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) if you can, or at least do it accurately <sub>Don't call timestamps dates</sub>
4. Until you are [formatting time data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?#date-and-time-styles) for *users*, stick to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Very nicely presented. Unfortunately, I think the last (and most challenging) field (RN)  is missing.

Comment: RN is a custom column OP added to help achieve the task. It can be accomplished without it, as RN is the same as the row number when partitioned by (SKU, Date)

Comment: Well, they have in it the desired result. It can be argued it's there to help us understand though.

Answer (score 0):

Just take your query and add `desc` to the `order by` in the `over` clause.

Then, use a subquery or CTE, and add:

```
where rn = 1
```

to the outer query.

That would be something like:

```
select . . .
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sku order by PriceChangeDate desc) as rn
     from . . .
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

If you actually want the number of price changes (what you call `rn`), then add `count(*) over (partition by sku)`.

I should note that this is often more efficiently accomplished using:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.PriceChangeDate = (select max(t2.PriceChangeDate) from t t2 where t2.sku = t.sku);
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(sku, PriceChangeDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
     SKU INT NOT NULL--use an appropriate data type here
    ,PriceChangeDate DATETIME NOT NULL    
    ,NewPrice MONEY NOT NULL
    ,OldPrice MONEY NOT NULL
    ,RN INT
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
(
     SKU
    ,PriceChangeDate
    ,NewPrice
    ,OldPrice
    ,rn
)
VALUES
     (1, '2017-01-01 01:00', 7.00, 6.50,1)
    ,(1, '2017-01-01 01:30', 6.75, 7.00,2)
    ,(1, '2017-01-01 01:45', 7.25, 6.75,3)
    ,(2, '2017-01-01 01:05', 8.75, 8.00,1)
    ,(2, '2017-01-01 01:25', 10.00, 8.75,2)

 SELECT    mx.SKU,
           mx.PriceChangeDate,
           mx.NewPrice AS NewPrice,
           mn.oldPrice AS OldPrice,
           mx.rn AS RN 
      FROM 
         (
             SELECT *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY PriceChangeDate DESC ) AS maxval
               FROM @MyTable 
          ) mx
   INNER JOIN
         (
               SELECT *,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY PriceChangeDate  ) AS minval
                 FROM @MyTable 
          ) mn
       ON mx.SKU = mn.SKU
      AND mx.maxval = mn.minval
    WHERE mx.maxval = 1
      AND mn.minval = 1;
```